# When migrating Wordpress to Google Cloud Platform from Linode I am getting a very slow response

Tags: wordpress

I recently moved my site set up from Linode to Google Cloud Platform.

I deployed Wordpress in the Google Cloud Platform and migrated my site to Google Cloud Platform.

We are running the latest version of Wordpress and our database size is around 70-80mb.

My homepage is not larger than 7mb.

The problem I am facing is an extremely slow response when my browser pings my Google Cloud IP. Our TTL is at godaddy default settings.

Any help on this would be great. My site is: https://ihb.io/

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your DNS records and checking latency I didn't notice anything obvious.

However, when I load your page my browser seems to constantly make GET requests every few seconds. I suggest loading your page with a developer mode turned on so you can see the network usage or use a free tool like this:

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/QKUiu/ihb.io

Which shows pretty clearly that while your homepage is 7mb, 231 requests were needed to load it. This causes a large overhead. You should try and reduce the number of requests needed to load your website.

Comment: Looking into this now. Thank you